# How to make filter setting in SQL Server database to show selected tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have many tables in SQL Server database. I would like to apply the filter setting on the tables, see screenshot below.

If I would like to filter all table name starting with K, I can write K in Name row, Value column and it shows me all tables which contains K letter.

What if I would like to show all tables with contains K and L letters. How should I set this multiple criteria? It shows no table if I write e.g. K, L. Any possible solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6nXx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to write multiple conditions with OR logic in SSMS.

[Check this link](https://bertwagner.com/posts/filtering-tables-procedures-and-other-objects-in-ssms/)

The other approach it to query the `sys.tables` metadata table

```
 SELECT 
     name 
 FROM sys.tables 
 WHERE name = 'L%' OR name = 'K%';
```

Comment: The query works fine when I run it without WHERE clause and shows all the tables but does not work with WHERE  clause and shows 0 results.
Secondly my objective is not to show the tables in the output "Results" tables, instead I would like to see the table filtered in the "Object Explorer" window on the left side when I click on the tables under that particular database.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot have multiple filter conditions in the Object explorer.